# returning pointer to a function inline without typedef

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm running into syntax errors with C++ where I have to return a pointer to a function inline.

```
struct Note{}
```

**Observer.hpp**

```
class Observer {
    protected:
        void (*notify)(Note *note); // should this be *(*notify...)?
    public:
        void (*(*getNoteMethod)())(Note *note);
};
```

**Observer.cpp**

```
void (*Observer::getNoteMethod())(Note*) { //error: non-static data member defined out-of-line
    return this->notify;
}
```

I'm getting this error, error: non-static data member defined out-of-line

I'm new to C++ and attempting to define the return function signature correctly.

Comment: These things usually become much more readable if you introduce a type alias (`typedef` or `using`).

Comment: I agree, but for learning reasons, I'm exploring that there should be a way, I was able to do this perfectly fine in C.

Comment: I don't think it's a great idea to learn something that literally nobody does.

Comment: Please note that *member functions* are different from free functions. You can't point to the `notify` function of `Observer` with `(void(*)(Note*))`. This is because member functions have a hidden parameter, the object pointer. (The instance of `Observer` it is operating upon.) If you want to point to `notify` you need a pointer to a member function.

Comment: @TarickWelling `notify` is a member variable with function pointer type, not a member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the declaration syntax for the member function (which returns function pointer). Declare it as:

```
class Observer {
    protected:
        void (*notify)(Note *note);
    public:
        void (*getNoteMethod())(Note *note);
};
```

Better to declare the function pointer type in advance via `using` or `typedef`, which looks much clearer. E.g.

```
class Observer {
    using function_pointer_type = void(*)(Note*); // the function pointer type
    protected:
        function_pointer_type notify;             // the data member with function pointer type
    public:
        function_pointer_type getNoteMethod();    // the member function returns function pointer
};

// Out-of-class member function definition
Observer::function_pointer_type Observer::getNoteMethod() {
    return this->notify;
}
```